# Not letting user print or save data

Tags: scripting

Can we stop user not to print our webpage or save it with the use of some scripts of some kind of that?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. You won't stop users trying to rip the page and will annoy legitimate users. Even if you *do* find a way, how will you prevent a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop people saving the web page from the browser unless you control what browser they use.

Most browsers will create a temporary file on the user's disk in order to cache your page, therefore it is already saved. There are 0 things you can do to prevent this.

Everything you put into a web page has to reach the user's computer, therefore you cannot stop them from saving it. If they really want your content they can just grab the packets before they hit the browser, thus circumventing anything you might do.

If you do not want people to be able to keep your content, do not give it to them.